# Highcharts shown in multiple divs with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, highcharts

i`m having troubles with the function each, i want to load a highcharts in different divs with the same name, with an ajax function so it reloads.

I was reading an old post where the chart was loaded this way:

```
$('.portlet_content_18').each(function(){
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: this,
        height: 400
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
}));
```

Thing that work for me but not when i change to the ajax call.

My code working with the ajax call, only loading in the first div with the name "graphcontainer" is the next:

```
function graph() {
    $(function () {

        $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
            // Create the chart
            window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'graphcontainer'
                },
                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'AAPL',
                    data: data,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I tried to add the each function so it loads in the other divs with no results.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: You have multiple DIVs on your page with the same name? Or you want the same chart loaded into multiple (uniquely) named DIVs?

Comment: I have multiple DIVs with the same name.

Comment: Okay. Well, that is different. So multiple DIVs with same name and you want to load the same chart into all of them? Then I would assume the user would be able to manipulate the chart to their own needs with same starting set of data?

Comment: Did you try removing the `renderTo: 'graphcontainer'` when you changed it to the foreach?

Comment: Not exactly, the thing is that i`m developing a phonegap application where in smartphones i show the chart in a different page, and for tablets i can show the chart in the first page. So i`m searching the best way of doing these. If i load the chart when the user change the page it takes more time to load. I try to use "this", but doesnt work at all.

Comment: Interesting. Sorry I cannot be of much more help here - I am not familiar with phonegap developing.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know in case that i change the id of one of them, if i can put to targets in the renderTo option?. Or who i suposed to do?.

Comment: Yes, you could create a loop for each DIV id value and call your chart create within that loop with the appropriate DIV id value as the renderTo value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to HighChart  [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo) and HighStock [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.renderTo):

```
renderTo: String|Object
The HTML element where the chart will be rendered. 
If it is a string, the element by that id is used. 
The HTML element can also be passed by direct reference. Defaults to null.
```

First, Highchart requires passing `"id"` of div element. So, I doubt how passing class name works with first example you have mentioned.

Can you please share from where did you get the former `HighChart` example ?

Second, Do you have a div containing `id="graphcontainer"` and included `Highstock` like

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

Comment: I read the documentation too, i fix the problem passing the container that i want as a parameter of the function graph, so i charge it when i need it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GabrielCandia: Good to hear that. Please keep practice of accepting helpful answers. :)